# jQuery issue selecting a specific element for a CSS3 flip animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modified css3 flip div demo which I am having problems with. I can make the div flip no problem and display the other side but my back side doc which has a cross to 'close' the div (basically remove the class) never works. Can someone see what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction

```
$('.close-face').on('click', function(){
    var card = $(this).closest('flip');
    alert(card.html());
    card.removeClass('flipped');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/10424/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you click on the `.flip` element, the class is added back again. Only add the class `flipped` when clicking on the front of the card in order to prevent it from being added when clicking the back.

In addition, you were trying to remove the class `.flipped` from the `.flip` element, meanwhile the class is on the `.card` element. Just target the `.flipped` element instead.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5wdjL4n4/)

```
$('.flip .front').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').addClass('flipped');
});


$('.close-face').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.flipped').removeClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(this).closest('.flip')`. You missed the dot.

You should also remove the class from `$(this).closest('.card')`